# I have an observation and I need to make a column with SAS

Tags: sas

I have an observation and I need to make a column with SAS
I tried split, I tried transpose, but nothing...

```
I have:


   num first second third
    1     13     17     16
    2     23     11     64

I need:


 num  var_n
   1  13
      17
      16
   2  23
      11
      64
```

Can you give me some advice, please

Comment: Is that a sas data table or a report?

Comment: I need proc report

Comment: Please do not ask the question multiple times. You've had solutions presented already, if they don't work, comment on there. Post the code you've tried as well.

Comment: @tanya You want an answer but won't take the time to ask a clear question? That's not really how this works in the long run. Since this is your first time on here, people are more likely to be lenient, but you really should take the time to at least form your question. You've been provided instructions in several of your posts on how to ask a question and where to look, but haven't even provided a sample of code that you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

`Proc Transpose` is already the right step to get your data in shape. `Proc report` is only used to display IDs only once.

```
data wide;
   input num first second third;
   datalines;
    1     13     17     16
    2     23     11     64
    ;
run;

proc transpose data = wide out= long (rename=(col1 = var_n)) ;
    by num;
    var first second third;
run;

proc report data = long;
    column num  var_n;
    define num/ order;
run;
```

Comment: You should add `nowd` to your proc report statement - this isn't required in SAS 9.4+ but is for lower versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the third time you've asked the same question. You can use proc transpose or proc sql to get it done.

See your other post: [How to make a column of three. SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340643/how-to-make-a-column-of-three-sas)

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
proc sort data=dataset;
   by num;
run;

proc transpose data=dataset out=transpose;
   by num;
   var first second third;
run;
```

thanks