# Concatenation in SAS

Tags: sas

Help my with my task, please. I have a problem:

```
Name Age Height Eyes
Dan  25   174   Blue
Dan  54   165   Black
Jane 33   160   Blue
Kate 19   170   Green
```

I need:

```
Name Characteristic
Dan     25
        174
        Blue
Dan     54
        165
        Black
Jane    33
        160
        Blue
Kate    19
        170
        Green
```

I tryed to do it with concatenation:

```
Characteristic=Age||Height||Eyes
```

But it makes one line from characteristics, but not a column:

```
Name   Characteristic
Dan    25 174 Blue
Dan    54 165 Black
Jane   33160 Blue
Kate   19 170Green
```

I knew, I need use split to solve this moment. Help me, please with some advice

Comment: Do you need this as a report or a table? This is NOT a concatenate problem.

Comment: I need to do it with proc report. I tryed to make a new database with column characteristic, using concatenation and make a report then.

Comment: This has actually been asked a few times before. Seems to be some textbook question. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357332/i-have-an-observation-and-i-need-to-make-a-column-with-sas

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it all to character to have it one field. You may also be able to use a `data _null_` step to create your report.

Here's how you could transpose your data to one field that you could then use proc report on. This is a transpose problem, not concatenation.

```
data have;
input Name $ Age Height Eyes $;
cards;
Dan  25   174   Blue
Dan  54   165   Black
Jane 33   160   Blue
Kate 19   170   Green
;
run;

data want; 
set have;
characteristic = put(age, 8. -l); output;
characteristic = put(height, 8. -l); output;
characteristic = Eyes; output;
drop age height eyes;
run;
```

If you were creating a text file or a different output this may be what you want:

```
data _null_;
set have;
file '/folders/myfolders/want.txt' dlm=" ";
put Name "09"x Age;
put "09"x Height;
put "09"x Eyes;
run;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: point is that all characteristics: age height eyes = characteristic - needs to be the one cell

Comment: Wouldn't proc report accomplish that, once the data was in the correct structure? I did ask if you needed a report or table. Your solution will also depend on your output destination, what are you using, Text file, HTML, RTF, PDF?  This structure doesn't make sense for a SAS dataset.