# Grouping values in DB SAS

Tags: sas

Help to solve the problem, please. I have some ideas, but none of them gives the desired result. DB have

```
Site Num Pres Began Start A B C
01   101 yes  no    yes   1 1 3
01   101 no   yes   yes   2 1 7
01   102 yes  yes   no    1 2 1
```

DB want (txt-file)

```
Site  Num  Pres Began Start  Quantity
01    101  yes  no    yes    1
                             1
                             3
01    101  no   yes   yes    2
                             1
                             7
01    102  yes  yes   no     1
                             2 
                             1
```

If you have any thoughts on this, I will be very grateful!!!

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I tryed to make a new variable quantity:
Quantity=Pres;
output;
Quantity=Began;
output;
Quantity=Start;
output;

Comment: I tryed to make a new variable quantity:
Quantity=Pres;
output;
Quantity=Began;
output;
Quantity=Start;
output;
and new variable which=pres if quantity=pres, new variable which=began if quantity=began. etc

Comment: I wrote a solution to a very similar problem here, with an example of outputting to a text file. If it doesnt work post your code AND log. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37129406/1919583